# Automatically cd into directories?

Tags: bash, directory, command-line

In the terminal You use `cd ../../........` to get to wherever you want,

But I am lazy, I am wondering if it is possible to automatically cd into the directories if the command is simply the directory.

The terminals obviously know it's the directory because you get the output of

> **$ ../**
>   bash: ../: Is a directory

So is it possible to hijack this message to automatically cd into that directory?

Comment: lol that is lazy. Just be careful some direcotires and executables share the same name, that's why typing cd is better.

Comment: laziness is a virtue

Answer (score 20):

Add `shopt -s autocd` to your `~/.bashrc`.

Also, you might want to run `man shopt` in terminal for more useful [options](http://ss64.com/bash/shopt.html).

Comment: Yes. This Works perfectly. I can also use cd foldername in order to change directory in the common way but, how can I remove such functionality and revert to default? Thanks in advance.

Comment: shopt -u autocd  -- read the link man.

Comment: `info bash --index-search='shopt'` or [Gnu Bash Reference - Shopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)

Comment: this prints out `cd -- /directory/path` is there a way to silence that?

Comment: @Fuseteam You can use the full cd command and not get output. There is a good reason that this shopt shortcut prints output -- so you don't end up running irrevocable commands after having changed dirs accidentally.

Comment: but i know i cded and the full path is always shown..... at the same time the convenience of autocd is hard to pass by.....