# my terminal look like this! can i change it?

Tags: command-line, 20.04

[image: this is my terminal]

my terminal shows the model of my laptop and not any directory. whenever I try to access a directory it shows no such directory when it actually exists. Even the home directory! I think the problem is this. is there any solution or am I just mistaken? I am new to linux and ask ubuntu so please do forgive me if I am making any mistake. any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: For your second issue, please see [trying to change to a file directory in the terminal but I am having trouble](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320065/trying-to-change-to-a-file-directory-in-the-terminal-but-i-am-having-trouble)

Comment: @steeldriver ok! thanks

Comment: @steeldriver I read that post but it doesnt solve my issue. When I use the absolute path it shows no such file or directory and i can't use the relative path because the current directory the terminal in my image shows doesn't exist.

Comment: Unless you have enabled the `autocd` option, you will need the `cd` command to access (**c**hange to **d**irectory) - simply typing the file or directory name attempts to execute the file

Comment: @steeldriver i use the cd command when i have to change the directory.

Comment: ... that's not what your screenshot shows...

Comment: @steeldriver the screenshot was meant to display the hostname not the command.

Comment: if any of these answers answer your question, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to the very long hostname, if you do not want your machine to be called `hasan-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK` on the network and in the terminal, you can use the `hostnamectl` command.

Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Set a new hostname:

   ```
   hostnamectl set-hostname <new-hostname>
   ```

   ***Note:** There is no output when you do this, so do not be surprised if it looks like "nothing happened".*
2. Confirm that everything is good by typing just `hostnamectl`. You should see something like this:

   ```
      Static hostname: my-computer
            Icon name: computer-laptop
              Chassis: laptop
           Machine ID: f45f012d60fc49fabea7b623cd7ae891
              Boot ID: 6aee67bd6bc647158dc2a3c4e43d34c3
     Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
               Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-66-generic
         Architecture: x86-64
   ```
3. Close Terminal
4. Re-open Terminal

Your hostname will now be the new value.

Answer (score 2):

Your prompt says you are in `~`, which is your home directory. `/lenovo` is an [**absolute path**](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001708.htm#linux). But that path does not exist, hence the error.

- Relative path ---> `relative/path/to/directory`
- Absolute path starts with `/` ---> `/absolute/path/to/directory`

If this directory existed, it would still not work (unless you have [`autocd` enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297985/automatically-cd-into-directories)), but with a different error message: `Is a directory`.
Use `cd directory` to change to a directory or `ls directory` to list its contents.

---

***If*** `lenovo` is a directory in your `$HOME`, you can type `cd lenovo` (relative path) from your `$HOME` or an absolute path like `cd ~/lenovo` or `cd /home/hasan/lenovo` to change to that directory.

Comment: thank you very much for explaining and especially telling me about the 'ls' command. I figured out what was going on.